# Horspool Algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm

I'm currently trying to implement the horspool string matching algorithm in C. It works for small data sets, but it for some reason won't work with a large data set.

Here's my createTable function:

```
void tableCreate(char* string, int table[]) {
    int i = 0;
    int length = strlen(string);

    for (i = 0; i < 500; ++i) {
        table[i] = length;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < length - 1; ++i) {
        table[string[i]] = length - i - 1;
    }
}
```

and here is the actual implementation:

```
//table is a global variable
int table[500];

pattern = calloc(256, sizeof(char));
pattern = fgets(pattern, 255, stdin);
pattern[strcspn(pattern, "\n")] = 0;
length = strlen(pattern);

tableCreate(pattern, table);

char c;
int count = 0;
char buffer[255];

while (fgets(buffer, 255, file) != NULL) {
    int stringLength = strlen(buffer);
    int j = 0;

    while (j <= stringLength - 1) {
        c = buffer[j + length - 1];

        if (pattern[length - 1] == c && memcmp(pattern, buffer + j, length - 1) == 0) {
            count++;
        }

        j += table[c];
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I can't provide the large data set because it's upwards of 40,000 lines. The small data set that I was testing was a small two sentences.

gdb output of infinite loop/segfault:

```
j: 48
stringLength: 78
length: 5
Shifting
j: 48
table[c]: 0
j: 48
stringLength: 78
length: 5
Shifting
j: 48
table[c]: 0
j: 48
stringLength: 78
length: 5
Shifting
j: 48
```

The above output is the result of print statements run in gdb.

Comment: "Unfortunately I can't provide the large data set because it's upwards of 40,000 lines" - then start reducing it and see what you can cut while still demonstrating the error.

Comment: @user2357112 I'll start doing that now.

Comment: It would also be worth showing what you're using as the search string.  How long is it?  How many repeated sub-patterns are there in it?  Presumably, it's a good bit shorter than 255 bytes since that's how long your lines are.  Did you consider trying POSIX function [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) instead of `fgets()` — or doesn't it matter because the input lines are short enough that 255 isn't a problem?  Maybe you should the first 5 and last 5 lines of your 40,000 line sample?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I've been using a search string of "economics" which should result in a matching of 37. The file format I'll post a copy of online, the lines are longer than 255.

Comment: I've also taken the liberty of posting some outputs with other search checks. I tried running "Apple" through the string match and it resulted in an infinite loop where j was always 48, table[c] was always 0, and stringLength was always 78.

Comment: Where does the 500 come from?  I looked at [Horspool algorithm](http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~lecroq/string/node18.html#SECTION00180), and the code there uses `ASIZE`, which I think is the alphabet size.  So I think I'd expect to see 255 or 256 in use rather than 500 — but I've not done a detailed comparison.  (You'd need to look at [Boyer-Moore](http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~lecroq/string/node14.html#SECTION00140) too to get the `preBmBc()` function.)

Answer (score 1):

This causes overflow when you approach the end of the buffer:

```
while (j <= stringLength - 1) {
    c = buffer[j + length - 1];
```

Should be:

```
while (j <= stringLength - length) {
    c = buffer[j + length - 1];
```